# How to get common indices from a set of pandas dataframes (more than 2)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of pandas dataframes (more than 2. I do actually have ~250 but this number is going to increase, so I'll need something better than a for loop) indexed on date column (type: datetime.date). 
I need to get the most recent date that is present in all the dataframes.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? And do you want to end up with a list of the latest date for all dataframes or one single value representing the latest value of all dataframes combined?

Comment: So far I used two for loops, and I only need the one most recent date common to all the index. Typically I do:

Comment: Are your indexes sorted by date?

Comment: Yes, all the indexes are sorted 'crescently' from the less recent date to the more recent